# Failed redundancy measures on google script for sending emails via google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to send a reminder for a weekly webinar with emails that live on a Google Sheet using Google's script editor/codelab. The link for the tutorial it's based off of is here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails

In their second section of code they post, it is an improved version because after the email is sent it populates a column with "EMAIL_SENT" and should prevent a duplicate email being sent out because "EMAIL_SENT" occupies that space (as I understand it).

My problem is that after I run the script, I'm able to get the emails to send off (I used three email accounts and each one received it), but I also get an error that reads:

```
Failed to send email: no recipient (line 24, file "macros").
```

Macros is the name of the file. The other issue I'm having is that if I run the script again after EMAIL_SENT has populated, it still sends an additional email even though it's not supposed to.

I've tried making the object in the first portion of the code different numbers to try and capture the right data. After I got the right data in there I don't understand why the other portions won't work.

```
`// This constant is written in column C for rows for which an email
// has been sent successfully.
var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';

/**
 * Sends non-duplicate emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
 */
function sendEmails_w_verification() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 116; // First row of data to process
  var numColumns = 8;
  var startColumn = 1;
 // Fetch the range of cells as object
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, startColumn, 
sheet.getLastRow(), numColumns);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[1]; // Second column
    var message = "Thank you for registering for the webinar"; // Second 
column
    var emailSent = row[8]; // ninth column
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) { // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = 'AFWERX Webinar Reminder';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 9).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
     // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is 
interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Expected duplicates not to send and no error message of "Failed to send email: no recipient (line 24, file "macros")" when the email sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first no recipient error seems to be caused by how you're starting your for loop, if you switch it to `i++` instead, the script runs fine. This is because by using `++i` you're picking up an extra row which doesn't have any email address in it, causing it to throw the "no recipient" error you're getting.

The second issue with the script not being able to check against column 9 is because the range you defined is only 8 columns wide, not 9. I found this by using a simple `Logger.log(emailSent)` which came back as `undefined`, which is what you'd expect to see if the value isn't even being defined in the range at all.

```
// This constant is written in column C for rows for which an email
// has been sent successfully.
var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';

/**
* Sends non-duplicate emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
*/
function sendEmails_w_verification() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 1; // First row of data to process
  var numColumns = 9;
  var startColumn = 1;
  // Fetch the range of cells as object
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, startColumn, sheet.getLastRow(), numColumns);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[1]; // Second column
    var message = "Thank you for registering for the webinar"; // Second     column
    var emailSent = row[8]; // ninth column
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) { // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = 'AFWERX Webinar Reminder';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 9).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

I've changed the for statement to use `i++` rather than `++i` which fixes the "no recipient" error message.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
```

Then changed your `var numColumns` to 9 rather than 8 so that it can see the column you're trying to check with your `if` statement.

```
var numColumns = 9;
```